# Migrating user data

Tags: 6, users, migrations

I am trying to migrate user data. There aer around 500 users that needs to be migrated. Problem is that these 500 users are registered in old site and i cant just insert these to new DB as new users are registered so uid of new user and these 500 users will collide , to avoid these i wrote a script to read all these data again and using user_save i am re inserting them , but the problem is

```
$new_user = array(
        'name'   => $row[name],
        'mail'   => $row[mail],
        'pass'   => $row[pass],
        'status' => $row[status],
        'init'   => $row[init]
    );
```

Here 'pass' is already md5 so when saving using `$account = user_save('',$new_user);` it is md5 hashed again ! 
Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a drupal way of doing this that does not use md5.

My first thought is to save the user w/o a password. The user object should then have a uid which you can use in SQL to insert the existing hashed password into the user's password field.

```
db_query("UPDATE {users} SET pass ='%s' WHERE uid = %d", pass, $new_user->uid);
```

Comment: Ok i am doing this in next step to save profile values user_save((object) array('uid' => $account->uid),$profile_val); so can i alter this and add pass field with existing md5 hash pass next to uid in array ? Or a manual update sql query ?

Comment: I would do the manual update sql query shown above. But I'm curious as to why you are setting the uid. Drupal should set that for you when you run [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_save/6)

Comment: I am doing it in 2 steps , creating user , then for that user adding profile values